# How to load multiple wallet ? Proper way to handle multiple wallet like account wise wallet

Tags: wallet, litecoin, wallet.dat, daemon, cli

I am trying understand the multiple wallet.I took the reference [from this link](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/v0.15.0.1rc1/doc/release-notes-litecoin.md#multi-wallet-support)

What I want to do ?

Right now in single wallet we can create multiple accounts and each accounts can have multiple addresses using `getnewaddress` command from `-cli`

So when we start coin core daemon to load multiple wallet its required to pass wallet file too(correct me if I am wrong here) like below

```
./hellocoind -wallet=john.dat -wallet=jimmy.dat
```

***Question :***

Is it proper way to give multiple wallet with `-wallet` & argument ? and what if any new wallet created if the daemon has been started with two wallet.

***eg. after starting daemon with john & jimmy 's wallet want to create new wallet (jack's wallet).***

So in above example do I need to stop(`./hellocoin-cli stop`) daemon and start daemon again with 3 wallets(`./hellocoind -wallet=john.dat -wallet=jimmy.dat -wallet=jack.dat`) ?

As I wants to create user wise wallet. Not like single wallet will have multiple accounts.

***Other details***
[I am using litecoin source.](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/tree/0.15)

**For cli I am using like below(correct me if i am doing anything wrong)**

```
./hellocoin-cli -rpcwallet=jimmy.dat listaccounts
{
  "": 0.00000000
}

./hellocoin-cli -rpcwallet=john.dat listaccounts
    {
  "": 49054.98712000,
  "a": 0.00000000
}
```

**For Rest api using as below (correct me if i am doing anything wrong)**

```
curl --user hellocoinrpc:hello108local1234567890 --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "listaccounts", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://192.168.39.108:2301/wallet/john.dat
```

Output :

```
{"result":{"":49054.98712000,"a":0.00000000},"error":null,"id":"curltest"}
```

Thanks